# Preventing scanner from reading leftover input in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am wondering how I can stop the scanner from reading extra erroneous input from the user.

For example, I would like to read in the user input `2 one` as `2` into the variable `diam`, which the program below achieves.

The issue is then, that the next loop automatically detects the `one` leftover from the input, and executes the `if` statement accordingly.

I was able to work around this by creating two scanners, but unfortunately this is not allowed for this particular assignment.  In addition, we are required to use `.hasNextInt()` in our program.

How do I prevent this "spill-over" using only one scanner?  I have to assume this question has been posed before, but I did not have much luck finding an answer.

```
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the diameter of a "
            + "cylinder (in centimeters): ");
    // BEGIN: diameter input verification loop      
    for (;;) {
        if (!scnr.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print("Please enter an integer value "
                    + "(less than 2,147,483,648) as decimal digits: ");
            scnr.nextLine(); 
            continue;
        }
        diam = scnr.nextInt();
        if (diam >= 0) {
           //null statement
        } 
        else {
          System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer value: ");
          continue;
        }
    break;
    }
    //END: diameter input verification loop

    //prompts user for container height     
    System.out.print("Enter the height of a "
            + "cylinder (in centimeters): ");

    // BEGIN: height input verification loop        
    for (;;) {
        if (!scnr.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print("Please enter an integer value "
                    + "(less than 2,147,483,648) as decimal digits: ");
            scnr.nextLine(); 
            continue;
        }
        height = scnr.nextInt();
        if (height >= 0) {
           //null statement
        } 
        else {
          System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer value: ");
          continue;
        }
    break;
    }
    //END: height input verification loop`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple of approaches:

- As Tim notes, you can use `readLine()` to read a complete line from the user, then parse the line.  You could use `split`, or create a new Scanner to parse the line, or various other approaches.
- You can stick with a single `Scanner` and call `nextLine()` to discard unconsumed characters up to and including the next end-of-line.  Obviously, you need to do this *after* calling `nextInt()`.   For example:

  ```
  height = -1;
  while (height < 0) {
      if (!scnr.hasNextInt()) {
          System.out.print("Please enter an integer value "
                  + "(less than 2,147,483,648) as decimal digits: ");
      } else {
          height = scnr.nextInt();
          if (height < 0) {
             System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer value: ");
          }
      }
      scanner.nextLine();
  }
  ```

  (The above version of your code has restructured things to get rid of the `break` and `continue`.  The restructuring also allows me to put the readLine as an unconditional last statement for the loop.  I think it makes the logic easier to understand ...)

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to just read the entire line of input from the `Scanner`, and then retain only the first word.  For example, for the diameter of a cylinder you could use:

```
System.out.print("Enter the diameter of a cylinder (in centimeters): ");
String input = scnr.nextLine();
try {
    int diam = Integer.parseInt(input.split(" ")[0]);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.print("Please enter an integer value "
                + "(less than 2,147,483,648) as decimal digits: ");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, that does seem like an easy way of doing it. Although I forgot to mention that the assignment requires the use of '.hasNextInt', and I believe wants us to stick with the basic loops that we have learned thus far.  Although, I have no clue whether or not the grading program would mark the 'try' and 'catch' wrong. My apologies I will edit my question.

Comment: @FofX If you use `nextInt()` then you are by definition reading only a single token.  Your problem is that you want to handle the scenario where the user has entered _multiple_ tokens as input.

Answer (score 1):

```
// BEGIN: height input verification loop
        for (;;) {

            scnr.nextLine(); /* read fresh input, deleting the left over input */

            if (!scnr.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.print("Please enter an integer value " + "(less than 2,147,483,648) as decimal digits: ");
                scnr.nextLine();
                continue;
            }
            height = scnr.nextInt();
            if (height >= 0) {
                // null statement
            } else {
                System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer value: ");
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
```

You can simply add a `scnr.nextLine()` to remove the "old" `scnr` left over from the previous input. This fixes the spill-over problem.